# Comparing dates only by year, month and date?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say we have 2 Date objects in Javascript;

```
var d1 = new Date('...');
var d2 = new Date('...');
```

We do a comparison:

```
d1 < d2;
```

This comparison will always take into account hours, minutes, seconds.

I want it to only take into account the year, month and date for comparison.

What's the easiest way to do this?

jQuery is allowed aswell.

Comment: So, you want it to return false on d1 < d2 if both are same day?

Comment: Nope, I want to return equal if they're both for example '2012-02-21'.

Comment: I'm aware that [jQuery is great and does all things](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif), but this is a case where it's not needed.

Comment: var msToTime = d.getTime(); var msToLastMidnight = msToTime - (msToTime % (24*60*60*1000)); // Compare the latter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reset the `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`, and `milliseconds`:

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.setHours(0);
d1.setMinutes(0);
d1.setSeconds(0);
d1.setMilliseconds(0);
```

Or using [`setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours), which is less verbose:

```
var d1= new Date();
d1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And finally, to compare if the resulting `Date`s are the same use [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

```
d1.getTime() == d2.getTime()
```

Comment: don't forget `setMilliseconds`.

Comment: This is strange, but I'm still getting false when doing a d1 == d2. Maybe date comparison can never yield equal (should I use a function?)

Comment: now make it into a function that strips hours, minutes and millis and chuck it in Date's prototype :)
or better yet, write Date.sameDayAs() function.

Comment: @Tool, `Date` objects are object references, and although they may hold the same value they are not going to be the same object. If you want to compare the timestamps, either call `d1.valueOf() == d2.valueOf()`, or cast them to `Number` types, `+d1 == +d2`.

Comment: @Tool: Use `getTime()` to compare the object's timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

As an algebraic solution, you could just run a bit of math:

```
function sameDay(d1, d2) {
    return d1 - d1 % 86400000 == d2 - d2 % 86400000
}
```

The equation actually breaks down as:

```
function sameDay(d1, d2) {
    var d1HMS, //hours, minutes, seconds & milliseconds
        d2HMS,
        d1Day,
        d2Day,
        result;
    //d1 and d2 will be implicitly cast to Number objects
    //this is to be explicit
    d1 = +d1;
    d2 = +d2;
    //1000 milliseconds in a second
    //60 seconds in a minute
    //60 minutes in an hour
    //24 hours in a day
    //modulus used to find remainder of hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds
    //after being divided into days
    d1HMS = d1 % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    d2HMS = d2 % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
    //remove the remainder to find the timestamp for midnight of that day
    d1Day = d1 - d1HMS;
    d2Day = d2 - d2HMS;
    //compare the results
    result = d1Day == d2Day;
    return result;
}
```

This has the advantage of not losing data on the original `Date` objects, as `setHours` and the like will modify the referenced object.

Alternatively, a safe `sameDay` function using `setHours` could be written as:

```
function sameDay(d1, d2) {
    var a,
        b;
    a = new Date(+d1);
    b = new Date(+d2);
    a.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    b.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return +a == +b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set Hours, Minutes and Seconds to 0 manually for each Date :

```
var d1 = new Date('...');
d1.setHours(0);
d1.setMinutes(0);
d1.setSeconds(0);

var d2 = new Date('...');
d2.setHours(0);
d2.setMinutes(0);
d2.setSeconds(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would convert the Date object to their ISO date format (`"2012-09-20"`) which can be compared as a string lexicographically:

```javascript
function compareDates(d1, d2) {
  var isoDate1 = d1.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  var isoDate2 = d2.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  return isoDate1.localeCompare(isoDate2)
}
compareDates(new Date("2010-01-01"), new Date("2010-01-01")) // => 0
compareDates(new Date("2010-01-01"), new Date("2012-01-01")) // => -1
compareDates(new Date("2012-01-01"), new Date("2010-01-01")) // => 1
```